# How would I change a property of an image without knowing its ID?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to use the Sector variable that is sent to the SetSectorImage sub to name the image that is being changed (the images do already exist on the web form, I am only changing the URLs). A Google search only led me to an article on MSDN about the CallByName method but I don't know if it will work in this situation and of it will, I can't figure out how.

Here's the article if it helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22x2chfx.aspx

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Launcher
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SetSectorImage("Sector1")
        SetSectorImage("Sector2")
        SetSectorImage("Sector3")
    End Sub

    Sub SetSectorImage(Sector As String)
        Dim SectorStatus As String
        Try
            Using Reader As New StreamReader(Sector + ".txt")
                SectorStatus = Reader.ReadToEnd()
                Reader.Close()
                Sector_SHOULD_BE_USED_HERE.ImageUrl = ("~/Images/" + SectorStatus)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorMessage.Text = ("There was an error reading the status of: " + Sector)
            ErrorMessage.Visible = True
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I believe there is something like `Page.FindById(Sector)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have Images on the page:

```
<asp:Image ID="Sector1" />
<asp:Image ID="Sector2" />
<asp:Image ID="Sector3" />
```

You can access them with [Control.FindControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

```
Dim myControl1 As Control = FindControl(Sector)
Dim myImage As Image = myControl1
myImage.ImageUrl = ("~/Images/" + SectorStatus)
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to this over using CallByName?

Comment: @TrevorRowe:`FindControl` is standard part of ASP.NET. `CallByName` is more low level ([Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) based). `Reflection` is usualy supposed to be slower.  `CallByName` is general and works, but when there is an ambiguity (e.g. field and variable of the same name) can have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research on CallByName() and found that I can use it in this situation. The line to change the image URL would be:

```
CallByName(Sector, "ImageUrl", CallType.Set, "~/Images/" + SectorStatus)
```